# Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all functions $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ s.t. $\iint_{\mathbb{D}}|f(x-iy)|^2dxdy<1 \implies\mathcal{F}$ is normal

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all functions $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $$\iint_{\mathbb{D}} |f(x-iy)|^2dxdy<1.$$ Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

Attempt:
Suppose $\mathcal{F}=\{f_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$. We want to show that for every compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{D}$, there exists a subsequence $\{f_{j_k}\}$ that converges uniformly to some $f$ in $K$. This result will follow from Montel's Theorem if we show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded.

Consider an arbitrary compact subset $K$ in $\mathbb{D}$. For $r>0$, we have that $$\{D_r(x): x\in K\}$$ is an open cover of $K$. As $K$ is compact there exists a finite subcover of $K$, namely, $\{D_r(x_1),\dots,D_r(x_n)\}$.

I want to use the Mean-value property: If $f$ is holomorphic in a disc $D_R(z_0)$, then $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})\ d\theta,$$ for any $0<r<R$.

How can I apply this to the two-dimensional integral?

Comment: Is there a particular reason this is written with $f(x-iy)$ rather than $f(x+iy)$? Of course, the integrals are equal.

Comment: Just the way it was worded on this old prelim exam https://math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2511/2018/12/jan2011cpx.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < R < 1$ and $z \in  \Bbb D$ with $|z| < 1-R$ then $\overline{D_R(z)} \subset \Bbb D$ and
$$
|f(z)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z+re^{i\theta})|\, d\theta
$$
for $0 \le r \le R$. Multiplying this inequality with $r$ and integration with respect to $r \in [0, R]$ gives
$$
 \frac 12 R^2 |f(z)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\overline{D_R(z)}} |f(x+iy)|^2dxdy \, ,
$$
i.e.
$$
 |f(z)| \le \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\iint_{\overline{D_R(z)}} |f(x+iy)|^2dxdy \le \frac{1}{\pi R^2} \, .
$$
It follows that $\mathcal F$ is uniformly bounded on each disk $|z| < 1-R$, and therefore locally uniformly bounded.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by mutliplying the inequality with $r$ and integration with respect to $r\in[0,R]$? @Martin R

Comment: @Sham: $\int_0^R |f(z)|r \, dr \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}|f(z+re^{i\theta})|r\, d\theta dr$